# What is the right way to create a field variable in a code behind file and when is property required

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a little confused about the Simplient thing variables. I have an ASP.NET Page (not MVC).
I want to create a variable at the class level which by definition is field variable because it is within a class. Example: I have a page called example.aspx and in the code behind I have about 10 different methods. I need each method to access the variable.

The key here is, I will not be accessing this variable from any other file or page:

Which is the right way?

```
public partial class example : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private bool firstField;
public bool FirstField 
{
get { return firstField; }
set { firstField = value; }
}
```

***OR;*** because this variable will not be access outside of the page or class do I simply do this:

```
 public partial class example : System.Web.UI.Page
{
bool firstField;
```

I understand the use of the property for global variables but do I need to use it if the variable will not be accessed outside of a class? *(My books says nothing about this part)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a data member that you don't want to be accessible to other classes, then you can explicitly make it a simple *private field*. If you want to add logic to its read and write operations, make a private field but access it through a *private property*.

In any case, if you want to encapsulate the member to make it accessible only to the class, you'll have to *make it private* and *not expose it* through any public members.

Comment: So I could simply do this?  private bool firstfield; but it is private by default right?
Thanks for responding:

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Yes, a field is private by default. However, I recommend explicitly specifying the modifier, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The first example will allow access to firstField, as you are creating a public getter/setter which sets it value;

If firstfield is only to be used within the example class, you can make it private i,e,

private bool firstfield;